# shell: problems when comparing variables

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04

```
FIN_ARC="da"
DIRECTORIO=$(dir -1)
for ARC in $DIRECTORIO;
do
    if [ -f "$ARC" ]; # it's file
    then 
        ARC_AUX=$(cat $ARC | tail -1)
        ARC_AUX="${ARC_AUX#"${ARC_AUX%%[![:space:]]*}"}"   
        ARC_AUX="${ARC_AUX%"${ARC_AUX##*[![:space:]]}"}"  

        if [ "$FIN_ARC" = "$ARC_AUX" ];then
            echo "same"
        else
            echo "$ARC_AUX != $FIN_ARC"
        fi

    fi;     
done
```

return da != da

I understand that it compares the type of data, but I do not know how to make the comparison valid.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Try `if [ "$FIN_ARC" == "$ARC_AUX" ]`

Comment: I've tried it, but it's a mistake:
integration-ftp.sh: 49: [: da: unexpected operator

Comment: can you add `| od -c` after echo to see non printable characters `echo "$ARC_AUX != $FIN_ARC" | od -c`

Comment: very interesting! + echo da != da
+ od -c
0000000 357 273 277   d   a       !   =       d   a  \n
0000014

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.

Thanks to Nahuel's comment, I concluded that the variables are different due to the codification of the files. The file where I get the last line was downloaded via ftp.

regards